# jQuery Dialog - Undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have  JS function that calls a dialog

```
function SomeFunction {
$('#editformdialog').dialog('open');
}
```

That's obviously simplified. However, I get `a is undefined` I then add `console.log(typeof dialog);` and that brings back `undefined`

It works when using jQuery 1.7.1 but not 1.8.12 (needs to be latest). It works in Firefox and not Chrome.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: as far as i know u cant write functions without the () after the name?
`function SomeFunction() {
$('#editformdialog').dialog('open');
}`

Comment: How come version 1.8.12 is latest? The last stable release is 1.8.0. Also: what's "a" ? could you copy paste a larger chunk of your code (preferably with what comes above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js

Using the latest version and it's sorted!

Comment: There is now newer versions...https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui